# Django Middleware: object.__new__() takes no parameters

Tags: django, django-middleware

I am trying to get middleware to work with Django, but I get an error:

```
object.__new__() takes no parameters
```

I have added the middleware tuple:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

My view looks like so:

```
from middleware import my_mw
@my_mw  
def start(request):
    do stuff...
    return render_to_response('a.html', {})
```

middleware.py:

```
class my_mw(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        x = 6
        return None
```

I have also tried various other middleware functions that I have copy pasted from examples. I always get the same error. At this point I'd really just like to get any middleware function to work!

Answer (score 1):

I needed to add the middleware function to the middleware tuple:

```
 'my_app.middleware.my_mw',
```

And then I don't include @my_mw

Comment: As this answer is correct, so please mark it as correct answer so that others can see it as correct answer.